# Is there a bug with scrollbar-width css property in Chrome 121?

Tags: css, google-chrome, scroll, webkit, scrollbar

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar { /* Chrome and Edge (Webkit or Blink) */
    display: none;
}
body {       
    -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE and legacy Edge */
    scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
}
```

These styles are for hidding the scrollbar while allowing the user to scroll the content by other means, for example by the mouse wheel.

These styles worked in versions of Chrome, but not anymore in version 121. But see, if I comment out the `scrollbar-width` property line, then the scrollbar is hidden again in Chrome 121.

This property used to do nothing in Chrome prior to version 121, because it wasn't implemented, but now, it seems to be conflicting with `::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }`.

Also `scrollbar-width: none` is neither hiding the scrollbar in Chrome 121, as it should since this version?

Chrome version: 122.0.6261.58 (Build oficial) (64 bits)

### Workaround/solution:

This little tweak in the styles solves the problem:

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar { /* Chrome and Edge (Webkit or Blink) */
    display: none;
}
body {       
    -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE and legacy Edge */
}
@-moz-document url-prefix() { /* === Added this wrapper === */
    body {       
        scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
    }
}
```

The question still remains, is there a bug?

Comment: Just so you know, -ms-overflow-style isn't going to do anything in Edge because Edge is based on Chromium now, Globally, about 0.01% of users are still on legacy Edge, which got its last version in 2018. The webkit prefix for scrollbar is what will work in Edge.

Comment: Thanks @StephenMIrving, updated the question to clarify that.

Comment: No problem, I am sorry that I am useless for answering your actual question as I have never played around with trying to hide the scrollbar while still allowing scrolling as I'd worry about the effect on accessibility or people without scroll wheels on their mouse. I don't know how it worked in previous chrome versions to be able to compare and troubleshoot. Good luck though.